# Suspended users who have never logged in

Tags: plugin-development, users, login

This may sound paradoxal but here it is.

Membership based site.

A new user starts as suspended.
An admin unsuspends.

### The user uses the system.

If a membership expires, a user gets suspended again (in the cp).

I want (in the cp again, from a plugin) a list of of suspended users who have never logged in. New users basically...

```
craft.users.status('suspended').lastLoginDate(NULL)
craft.users.status('suspended').lastLoginDate('')
```

Neither of these work. Any light?

Doing this

```
craft.users.status('suspended')
```

Then this in the actual loop works

```
 {% if user.lastLoginDate is null %}
```

I just wonder why I can't just fetch it all in one go :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably works: `craft.users.status('suspended').lastLoginDate(':empty:')`

Comment: Perfect, this works just as I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

You should able to use `search` with `craft.users` something like this:

```
craft.users.search('suspended: 1 lastLoginDate: NULL')
```

See the [search docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching) for more details.

Comment: Cheers for that, I'm not a massive fan of search for set things like this but this works too :)